# Method not getting called (Core Location) Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, methods, sdk, call, core-location

Hey guys,
I'm trying to call the update method but its not working, any idea?

```
#import "TrackerViewController.h"

@implementation TrackerViewController

-(IBAction)updateButton:(id)sender{
    [self update];
    }

-(void)update{
    locmanager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; 
    [locmanager setDelegate:self]; 
    [locmanager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

    [locmanager startUpdatingLocation];


}


-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [self update];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{ 
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [newLocation coordinate];

    latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", loc.latitude];
    longtitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", loc.longitude];


}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{ 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `didUpdateToLocation` will be called when an location changes.

I guess you are testing it in simulator and on simulator no change occurs in location so the method don't called.

**Suggesstion** You should implement [other delegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html) to check whats happening; in case if there is some error. For example: `locationManager:didFailWithError:`